# Bash extract string with grep

Tags: string, shell, filter, grep

Lets say i got multiple strings in one file and i only want to extract a specific string

```
$plugin->component = 'mod_jitsi';
$plugin->component = 'local_hvp';
$plugin->component = 'test_bot';
$plugin->component = 'mod_bot';
$plugin->component = 'mod_moodle';
```

I want to filter this with grep so my output looks like this:

```
mod
local
test
mod
mod
```

Is there any way to do this with grep or do i need to use awk or sed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `$plugin->component = ` stay the same in all lines and you want to extract everything up to the first `_` in the rest of the string?

Comment: With `awk` it is in any case clearer: `awk -F "['_]" '{print $2}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '$plugin->component = 'mod_jitsi';
$plugin->component = 'local_hvp';
$plugin->component = 'test_bot';
$plugin->component = 'mod_bot';
$plugin->component = 'mod_moodle';' > STRING

awk 'BEGIN { FS ="=" } ; { print $2 }' STRING | cut -d "_" -f1



mod
local
test
mod
mod
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `grep` and pcre regular expressions:

```
grep -Po "(?<== ')[^_]*" input.txt
```

`(?<== ')` is a *zero-width positive lookbehind assertion*. It's not included in the matched text, but it must match the `= '` before the part of the RE that is included (Which is everything from after the quote to the first underscore.

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE):

```
grep -Po '\$plugin->component = '\''\K[^_]+' file
```

---

With `sed`:

```
sed -En 's/\$plugin->component = '\''([^_]+).*/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

PCRE is probably the best way, and you already have two answers that demonstrate how to use it.

There is, however, a more "elementary" way - using just BRE (basic regular expressions, used by plain `grep`). You just need to call it twice.

I assume that each input row has (at most) one substring consisting of a single quote, followed by zero or more non-single-quote, non-underscore characters, followed by an underscore, and you must extract the sequence of non-single-quote, non-underscore characters within this substring.

If the input strings are in a file `my_file`:

```
[mathguy@localhost ~/test]$ more my_file
$plugin->component = 'mod_jitsi';
$plugin->component = 'local_hvp';
$plugin->component = 'test_bot';
$plugin->component = 'mod_bot';
$plugin->component = 'mod_moodle';


[mathguy@localhost ~/test]$ grep -o "'[^'_]*_" my_file | grep -o "[^'_]*"
mod
local
test
mod
mod
```